# The replacement token 'description' has no value

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

Trying to create and publish a NuGet package from a project (*.csproj) via NuGet.exe and I got the following warning:

> The replacement token 'description' has no value.

How can I get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This warning appear when the Visual Studio project was not built *before* packaging using NuGet. Just rebuild your project and repack.

1. Go to **Build** then **Rebuild**.
2. From command prompt: `nuget pack your-project.csproj`.

Then it should work.

Note [this behavior was filed as an issue in CodePlex](http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/1999).

*Note: as per Boris Callens' response below, can use the `-Build` to have NuGet do the build*

Comment: had this problem, rebuild didn't work because i was building 'debug' and nupack-ing 'release'...

Comment: My issue was related to this one:
https://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/262324

It was defaulting to Debug configuration and the following command solved my problem:
NuGet.exe pack Foo.csproj -Prop Configuration=Release

Answer (score 27):

Ensure you defined the assembly description in your Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs file for the project you are targeting when calling nuget.exe pack *.csproj.

```
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("Here goes the NuSpec $description$ token.")]
```

Also check the NuGet docs on tokenized NuGet manifests for more info: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuspec-reference#Replacement_Tokens

Comment: Lovely! This is really the answer to the question. Adding your post about $version$ as well - for reference: http://www.xavierdecoster.com/post/2012/04/26/nuget-version-token-explained

Answer (score 5):

The $description$ value is replaced by AssemblyDescription's value in AssemblyInfo.cs.
The project needs to be built before creating the package however. To have nuget do this for you you can use the -build flag

```
path:\to\project\nuget.exe [project.csproj] -build
```

Answer (score 5):

I have similar problem on "The replacement token 'author' has no value". 
I use **nuget pack projectfilename.csproj -Build** and problem is solved, hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

My builds are specific to x86 or x64 which puts the dlls in different bin subdirectories.  It is expecting the dll to be in the default directory which is for "Any CPU".  I'm not sure if you can change where it looks, but I just changed my release to Any CPU so that it would work.

Answer (score 1):

Also, make sure you pass your projectName.**csproj** file and NOT the projectName.**nuspec** file. This is the corect way:

```
nuget pack projectName.csproj
```