# Build NuGet Package automatically including referenced dependencies

Tags: visual-studio, build-automation, nuget, nuget-package

I want to [run a local/internal NuGet repository](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/31/hosting-simple-nuget-package-feed.aspx).  I think I've figured out how to "reuse" existing NuGet packages by including them in a dummy project using NuGet and scanning the package file to [grab my locally-cached `.nupkg` files](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToAccessNuGetWhenNuGetorgIsDownOrYoureOnAPlane.aspx), but...

### How do you create a nuget package (`.nupkg`) from a project, automatically including **all** `dll` dependencies and not just those grabbed via NuGet?

Specifically:

1. Create a solution
2. Add a new Project
3. Add references to various `.dll` files/other projects *<-- this is the missing part*
4. Add NuGet packages via package manager / cmdline / whatever
5. *something* automatically creates the `.nupkg`

From what I've found, you're supposed to do things like

- manually edit your `.csproj` file to add `<BuildPackage>true</BuildPackage>` to include dependencies
- manually create a `.nuspec` file and manually [list your dependencies](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuspec-reference#Specifying_Dependencies_in_version_2.0_and_above) ([similar ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12819868/nuget-packaging-and-referencing-dlls))
- manually run `nuget pack` on your `.nuspec` file

But everything is manual, which is stupid.  Even the semi-automatic solutions are still awkward or half-manual:

- [Create `.nuspec` templates](http://www.xavierdecoster.com/post/2012/04/27/install-package-nuspec-aspx) - doesn't seem to include dependencies, just metadata
- [nuget pack via build-event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180904/automating-creating-nuget-package-as-part-of-build-process) (step #5), which you need to add manually to every project, and it has [its own quirks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14982266/the-replacement-token-description-has-no-value):

  ```
  "$(SolutionDir).nuget\NuGet.exe" pack "$(ProjectPath)" -Properties Configuration=Release
  move /Y *.nupkg "$(TargetDir)"
  ```

I'll settle for something that automatically creates a `.nuspec` manifest from project references.  Then theoretically that + the nuget build-event can be rolled up into a build-project/nuget package, which is what I really want to see.

Comment: I just came across this VS extension http://www.eyecatch.no/projects/nuget-package-template/ which I'll need to look into...

Comment: Five years later and nuget 4.x spec or pack still can't determine dependencies.

Comment: Is there an update for this issue? Or do you still have these problems?

Comment: I gave up on this a while ago, but check out NuProj as reported by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39036687/1037948)

Comment: This issue still exists. :(

Comment: There's a really good fix described here (no need to specify dependencies by name or even by search string): https://stackoverflow.com/a/56691267/1863924

Comment: this answere helped in my case... https://stackoverflow.com/a/56691267/10036810

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Your point #3 (*Add references to various .dll files/other projects <-- this is the missing part*) really contains two different issues: (1) add references to various dll files, and (2) add references to other projects in the same solution.

Number (2) here has gotten some added support as of [NuGet 2.5](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/release-notes/nuget-2.5#Improved_project_reference_support_for_NuGet.exe_Pack). You can add an option to include references to other projects in the same solution when creating a NuGet package for a project:

```
nuget pack projectfile.csproj -IncludeReferencedProjects
```

- If `projectfile.csproj` references any other projects in your solution that also is exposed as NuGet packages, these projects' **NuGet packages** will be added as dependencies.
- If it references projects in your solution that *doesn't* expose themselves as NuGet packages, their **dlls** will be included in this NuGet package.

As for (1), if you find yourself often adding dlls to your projects that aren't available as NuGet packages, you could just create your own (internal) NuGet packages with these files. If you then add these dlls as a NuGet package instead of the files directly, this NuGet package will be a dependency in your project's NuGet package.

Comment: *sigh* #1 is still too manual for my tastes.  Actually, "create your own (internal) NuGet package with these files" is what I'm trying to do -- the whole point of this question is that I want to automatically roll up non-NuGet .dlls into a NuGet package.  Not go through and list each dll manually in a `.nuspec`, which I think is what you're suggesting?

Comment: You don't have to specify each DLL separately. That would indeed be much work if you have _many_ of them. When listing files to include, you can use (recursive) wildcards (http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuspec-reference#Specifying_Files_to_Include_in_the_Package), so if you for instance place all these DLLs in a separate folder, it would be a one-liner to include them all.

Comment: Ah, now I get where you're going -- so if I make a wrapper project, include references via the usual "right-click project > Add Reference", then I can make a `nuspec` that includes everything in the `bin` directory (assuming my references are all "copy local"), it'll automatically pick up on whatever I've added.  Seems a little hamfisted, but would probably work.

Comment: It won't automatically pick up whatever is in your bin directory, you'd have to specify it explicitly, something like this: `<file src="bin\release\*.dll" target="lib" />`

Comment: correct, that's what I meant by "automatic" `nuspec`; thank you for clarifying

Comment: Note worthy, if the projects being referenced happen to have a nuspec file then nuget will treat that as a package and NOT include in the lib folder but will add it to the package dependencies

Comment: Is there an equivalent to `IncludeReferencedProjects` for `.csproj`?

Answer (score 29):

I found a well-written article on this topic.  I have the same issue with certain packages that have a hierarchy of dependencies and up until now I've been uploading each as a separate NuGet package (what. a. waste. of. time)

I've just tested the solution found here: https://dev.to/wabbbit/include-both-nuget-package-references-and-project-reference-dll-using-dotnet-pack-2d8p

And after examining the NuGet package using NuGet Package Explorer, the DLLs produced by referenced projects are indeed present.  I'm going to test by actually submitting this package to NuGet and testing it.

Here's my source in case it is helpful to you: https://github.com/jchristn/NuGetPackTest

And the test NuGet package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGetPackTest/1.0.0

The solution appears to work well.  I don't know what it's going to look like when there are layers of references, I'm sure it could get really hairy and really fast.

[image]

.csproj from NuGetPackTest library which references project TestLibrary (portions removed for brevity)

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
 
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;netcoreapp3.0;netcoreapp3.1;net461</TargetFrameworks>
    ...
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>

    <!-- added this line -->
    <TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput>$(TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput);CopyProjectReferencesToPackage</TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>

    <!-- modified this ProjectReference to include the children ReferenceOutputAssembly and IncludeAssets -->
    <ProjectReference Include="..\TestLibrary\TestLibrary.csproj">
      <ReferenceOutputAssembly>true</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
      <IncludeAssets>TestLibrary.dll</IncludeAssets>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <!-- added this section -->
  <Target DependsOnTargets="ResolveReferences" Name="CopyProjectReferencesToPackage">
    <ItemGroup>
      <BuildOutputInPackage Include="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths->WithMetadataValue('ReferenceSourceTarget', 'ProjectReference'))"/>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
  
</Project>
```

Comment: This solution does not add the reference project's nuget dependencies as dependencies. So you will have to add all the nuget dependencies that are added in sub-projects to the main project that will be a nuget package. Atleast that is what I encountered, including the created nuget package in another project results in 'assembly or file not found' issues.

Answer (score 9):

For other Googlers, you can use this if you are using the NuGet.targets file to run NuGet Pack:

```
<Target Name="PrePackage" BeforeTargets="BuildPackage">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <BuildCommand>$(BuildCommand) -IncludeReferencedProjects</BuildCommand>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Target>
```

Comment: Sounds promising but not enough information to actually implement. What is this NuGet.targets file you speak of? I am familiar with build target files in general but not this specific use case

Comment: Also intersted how NuGet.targets can help, perhaps this notification will help in getting an answer update :)

Comment: Downvoted as I don't think this comment has aged well with time.

Comment: upvoted because aging time is not a valid criteria to downvote

Comment: if I have to include the non-referenced project ??

Answer (score 6):

I solved this for my case by adding the whole TargetDir to the nuget package.

Just add this to the .csproj:

```
<Target Name="IncludeAllFilesInTargetDir" AfterTargets="Build">
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="$(TargetDir)\**">
      <Pack>true</Pack>
      <PackagePath>tools</PackagePath>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Comment: I wish I understood how and why this works.

Answer (score 2):

Check this out!

The solution which I found is an extension for Visual Studio:
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fbe9b9b8-34ae-47b5-a751-cb71a16f7e96/view/Reviews

You simply add new project called NuGet Package:
[image: NuGet Package]

Then you are adding interesting you projects to references and BOOOM !!
All dependencies and file directories are automatically added.
If you want to modify NuSpec data you click right at project and go to Properties,
then modify what you want.
Generated NuSpec and nupkg will be in folder **obj** of your new project.
I hope it helps ;).

Comment: Is there also a solution for VS2017?

Comment: This does not work in case of generating the packages on build server.

Comment: Too bad this is deprecated.  Would have been useful.

Comment: I found a VS2017 version: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NuProjTeam.NuProj2017 and VS2019 version: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kamalraj.Nuproj201, although didn't have much luck on initial testing so just created the file manually in the end.

Answer (score 2):

The original NuGet pack would include local project dlls and if you used packages.config any nuget packages would be listed as dependencies. Everyone was happy.

Microsoft have since streamline everything, so now .Net (core) everything is done from the project file, which I do prefer. But now using **nuget pack**, your resulting package would have no dependencies listed.

Microsoft have said that the PackageReferences are not supported by the NuGet

[NuGet CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/cli-reference/cli-ref-pack)

So you need to use **dotnet pack** or **msbuild -t:pack**

[dotnet CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/dotnet-commands)

However now using dotnet pack you have you dependencies back for your PackageReferences but you ProjectReferences are now also listed as dependencies.....

below is an example project file, with PackageReferences and ProjectReferences. for the Projects they have been marked as **PrivateAssets="All"** and then using custom build targets to copy the files needed from the projects into the package.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Title>Some.Project</Title>
  </PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Something" Version="1.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.2" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\Some.Other.Project.csproj" PrivateAssets="All" />
</ItemGroup>

<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput> $(TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput);CopyProjectReferencesToPackage</TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="CopyProjectReferencesToPackage" DependsOnTargets="BuildOnlySettings;ResolveReferences">
  <ItemGroup>
  <_ReferenceCopyLocalPaths Include="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths->WithMetadataValue('ReferenceSourceTarget', 'ProjectReference')->WithMetadataValue('PrivateAssets', 'All'))"/>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <BuildOutputInPackage Include="@(_ReferenceCopyLocalPaths)" TargetPath="%(_ReferenceCopyLocalPaths.DestinationSubDirectory)"/>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
</Project>
```

[NuGet pack task doesn't include dependencies when using PackageReference #10301](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/10301)
[nuget pack is ignoring dependencies when using PackageReference instead of packages.config #5979](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5979)

Great guide and examples by Josef Ottosson
[Include Referenced Projects - Josef Ottosson](https://josef.codes/dotnet-pack-include-referenced-projects/)

Comment: how is this relevant for .dlls? Project references are not what was in the question.

Comment: @Schattenjäger if you have a solution with a number of class files they will be built as dll's and you need a way of including them unless you wish to package them all up separately.  Directly referencing dlls isn't really the done thing anymore but the same method above could be used to include them in a single package.