# Is it possible to have multiple NuGet configurations in one solution?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I'd begin with saying that I never had any experience with managing NuGet packages, even the simplest ones. However, I'm planning to use it in my next project, which design *could* rely on the answers to my question.

For a better understanding of the problem, let's assume we have the following projects, all under one solution:

- Core
- Foo
- Bar

Both **Foo** and **Bar** depend on **Core**, but not on each other.
As such, I'd like to create one nuget package for the **Foo** + **Core** combination, and one for the **Bar** + **Core** combination, without separating them to different solutions.

Is this scenario possible?

Comment: You should use nuget pack foo.csproj -IncludeReferencedProjects (note that the pack command is applied on foo) as IncludeReferencedProjects option also adds the dependencies of the referenced projects. Probable duplicate:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16173568/build-nuget-package-automatically-including-referenced-dependencies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your scenario is possible. NuGet package creation doesn't depend on the solution the project belongs to. 
You can either define your own nuspec file to pack a package or use a csproj file to do so. Look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/nuget-exe-cli-reference

Note: NuGet primarily packes .dll files into a package. Even if you use .csproj files, it looks at the  and picks up the .dll from that location. You can choose to store the Sourcecode using the NuSpec file though.

For a NuSpec file:

- What you want to pack entirely depends on you and you can what goes
  in, in the things in a NuSpec file.

For a .csproj file(I think this is what you should use):

- Use the `nuget pack <nuspecPath | projectPath> [options]` command
  `IncludeReferencedProjects` as an option, and `projectpath` for Foo and Bar individually. This would create two separate NuGet packages
  which fulfill your need.

Comment: Awesome! Let me know how it goes. Also, try using NuGet spec <csproj name> to autogenerate a NuSpec file in case you want to pursue that route.

Comment: @TimorGruber Please let me know if you solved the problem! Otherwise I can possibly help you out further.

Comment: Finally got time to check your solution, and guess what? It absolutely works! I used the *.csproj* approach, although I'm convinced that it's possible and maybe even better to use the **NuSpec** file.  
I marked your answer as the answer to this question, thank you very much.

Comment: Awesome to here! Yeah the NuSpec file approach gives you far more options, you can even pack useless things not part of any project. Guess what: Whenever you use a nuget pack .csproj, it automatically creates a nuspec file, and creates a package using that. This nuspec can be found when you unarchive the .nupkg file.  Also: Try using : `NuGet Spec <csproj path>` command when you want to create the nuspec file using the csproj metadata. Also, thanks for marking it as an answer, I CAN NOW COMMENT **EVERYWHERE**