# Force project references to be included in netstandard nuget package

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget-package, .net-standard

I have a netstandard project which includes two project references.  Visual studio 2017 is being used to build the nukpg.  When the project is built the produced nupkg only contains the assembly produced by that project and lists the two project references as nuget dependencies.  Is there a way to force the packaging to include those assemblies as lib files?

**csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net462</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>Verifier.Observations.DevOps.Health</RootNamespace>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <VersionPrefix>1.0.1</VersionPrefix>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Verifier.Observations.Aspects\Verifier.Observations.Aspects.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Verifier.Observations\Verifier.Observations.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.Composition"/>
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

[image]

**Update**
Based upon feedback from @alexgiondea-msft the package is now created as desired using the following

**csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VersionPrefix>1.0.1</VersionPrefix>
    <TargetFramework>net462</TargetFramework>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <NuspecFile>Verifier.Observations.DevOps.Health.Nuspec</NuspecFile>
   <NuspecProperties>version=$(VersionPrefix);id=$(MSBuildProjectName);author=$(Authors);copy=$(Copyright);iconUrl=$(PackageIconUrl)</NuspecProperties>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Verifier.Observations.Aspects\Verifier.Observations.Aspects.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Verifier.Observations\Verifier.Observations.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.Composition" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**nuspec**

```
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>$id$</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <title>$title$</title>
    <authors>$author$</authors>
    <owners>$author$</owners>
    <iconUrl>$iconUrl$</iconUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Inspect automation service to ensure it is up and operational</description>
    <releaseNotes></releaseNotes>
    <copyright>$copy$</copyright>
    <tags>verifier-observation-plugin automation</tags>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework="net462" />
    </dependencies>
    <references>
      <group targetFramework="net462">
        <reference file="Verifier.Observations.DevOps.Automation.dll" />
      </group>
    </references>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="bin\*\net462\*.dll" target="lib\net462" />
    <file src="bin\*\net462\*.pdb" target="lib\net462" />
  </files>
</package>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can control where assemblies are deployed in the nuget package using an item in an itemgroup, similar to this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="!!path_to_assembly!!">
        <PackagePath>lib\net462</PackagePath>
        <Pack>true</Pack>
        <Visible>false</Visible>
    </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

That should include the specified assembly in the package.

Comment: @alexgiondea-msft Alex thanks, the nuget package was created with the lib containing the assemblies.  However, the nupkg still included the project references as dependencies.  Is there an additional flag that can be set to prevent this listing?

Comment: I am setting up a repro similar to what you mention and see if / how to remove those dependencies.

Comment: Try adding this to the project references node. That should remove the dependencies to the project from showing up in the nuspec.


    <ProjectReference Include="!!project!!">
        <ExcludeAssets>all</ExcludeAssets>
    </ProjectReference>


For advanced scenarios like this you could also consider moving to an explicit .nuspec file for full control of the package.

Comment: The answer provided works perfectly, it was not easy to find this in any documentation. Took me a while to find this, thanks a lot. MS should improve their docs.

Answer (score 7):

You can add the following target to your .csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net47</TargetFrameworks>
    <TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput>$(TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput);CopyProjectReferencesToPackage</TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ClassLibrary2\ClassLibrary2.csproj" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ClassLibrary3\ClassLibrary3.csproj" Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net47'" PrivateAssets="all" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="CopyProjectReferencesToPackage" DependsOnTargets="ResolveReferences">
    <ItemGroup>
      <BuildOutputInPackage Include="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths->WithMetadataValue('ReferenceSourceTarget', 'ProjectReference'))" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

**[Source 1](https://github.com/nuget/home/issues/3891#issuecomment-501592455)**

**[Source 2](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4491#issuecomment-375501396)**

**Reference:** **[Advanced extension points to create customized package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#advanced-extension-points-to-create-customized-package)**

Comment: The accepted answer did not work for me with a .NET Standard 2.0 NuGet package, however this solution here worked for me!

Comment: Thank you! Have been looking for a solution for this for many hours, worked great.