# Create a NuGet with depedent projects

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, nuget, nuget-package

I have a .net solution consisting of 3 projects

- myproject.Interfaces
- myproject.Models
- myproject.Core

When I create a NuGet on myproject.Core:

```
dotnet pack c:\Dev\myproject.Core.csproj -c Release
```

and try to install it in another project it's saying that

> I'm missing .Models and .Interfaces.

Is there a way to **include**  myproject.Models and myprojects.Interfaces within .Core NuGet? so that I have to install ONLY .Core nuGet in my projects?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Build NuGet Package automatically including referenced dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16173568/build-nuget-package-automatically-including-referenced-dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

if your dependency is a nuget package you can add a dependency tag in your nuspec file

```
<dependencies>
      <group targetFramework=".NETCoreApp3.0" >
         <dependency id="myproject.Interfaces" version="3.0.1" />
         <dependency id="myproject.Models" version="3.0.1" />
      </group>
      <group targetFramework=".NETCoreApp3.1" >
         <dependency id="myproject.Interfaces" version="3.0.1" />
         <dependency id="myproject.Models" version="3.0.1" />
      </group>
    </dependencies>
```

but if your dependency is a dll you can add as a normal file

```
<files>
 <file src="lib\netcoreapp3.0\myproject.Interfaces.dll" target="lib\netcoreapp3.0\myproject.Interfaces.dll" />
 <file src="lib\netcoreapp3.0\myproject.Models.dll" target="lib\netcoreapp3.0\myproject.Models.dll" />
   
 <file src="lib\netcoreapp3.1\myproject.Interfaces.dll" target="lib\netcoreapp3.1\myproject.Interfaces.dll" />
 <file src="lib\netcoreapp3.1\myproject.Models.dll" target="lib\netcoreapp3.1\myproject.Models.dll" />
</files>
```

Comment: did not work. says: "Module blah blah version ' should be referenced.